# How to store a query in memory and reuse them in ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, webforms

I have a `ListView` in my ASPX page, inside my `ListView` I'm calling a function from my code behind which will process some data based on the Ids of that row as shown below:

ASPX:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvMembers" runat="server" ItemType="ExampleTable">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>-</th>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceHolder"></tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%# CalculateFromDatabase(Item.Ids) %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

C#:

```
public int CalculateFromDatabase(int Ids)
{
    return db.ExampleTable.Count(et => et.id = Ids);
}
```

I'm looking a way which I can optimize this, is there a way I can store db.ExampleTable in a variable, and then reuse it so that I don't need to requery the database everytime instead I can just requery the memory list which is faster?

Comment: Is this what you need: `var inmemory = db.ExampleTable.ToList()`? You can reuse `List` for subsequent LINQ queries.

Comment: Yes you can. Just get the result of the query in a class level variable but this number will never reflect the changes made to that table by other users in a multiuser environment

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yea I know I can store the list into memory like that, but in my `ListView`, I cannot reuse the variable.

Comment: @Steve Possible to show some example how can that be done? Are you saying that I'll need to instantiate the variable in `Page_Load` event?

Comment: _var count = db.ExampleTable.Count(et => et.id = Ids);_ then save that variable count in a Session variable where you can retrieve it when you need it

Comment: @Steve I had thought of storing the variable in a Session before, but I'm wondering will it cause performance issue if the List is too large?

Comment: What performance issue? You are retrieving an Integer not the whole list.

Comment: @Steve I'll need to retrieve a whole list and keep it to count other Ids later, if I only retrieving an integer it doesn't make sense for me to store in Session anymore

Comment: I don't know what to tell you about this then. You have the data, you know the frequency of the database calls. You know the memory and cpu limits of your server machine. You can try the define the extimated number of users of your site. I can only suggest to measure the performance at the best you can and try to make an educated guess.